# How to exclude Replication tables in select from sysobjects

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am running the following query and since the production database is using replication we are getting all the tables added for replication (ex. MSpeer_conflictdetectionconfigrequest, MSpeer_conflictdetectionconfigresponse) in the results.

```
SELECT name FROM sysobjects WHERE type='U' AND name != 'sysdiagrams'
```

We need to adjust this query so that those tables do not show up.  I of course could do a `name NOT IN ()` and list them all, but I am looking for a better solution.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using SQL 2008, I'd suggest the ff:

```
select * from sys.tables where is_ms_shipped = 0
```

Comment: Looking at the documentation for SQL 2005 for sys.objects, it looks like the is_ms_shipped column is present, so it should.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name .
FROM sysobjects 
WHERE type='U' 
  AND name != 'sysdiagrams' 
  AND replinfo = 0
```

However: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177596.aspx  note that sysobjects and replinfo seems deprecated.

```
0=not replicated
128 = merge - table or indexed view
1=transactional - table or indexed view - log based
3=transactional - table or indexed view - log based with custom sync object
33=transactional - table or indexed view - immediate updating

35=transaction- table or indexed view - log based with custom sync object
and custom filter
129 =merge and transactional - table or indexed view

64 - procs used by immediate updating
512 - all other procsprocs, views, functions
```